# How to query Android Room for current streak and longest Streak

Tags: android, sqlite, android-sqlite, android-room

Currently have a a table in android room that saves the day in a column in the format yyyy-MM-dd. I want to be query the longest streak of consecutive days and the current streak. How would I accomplish that in Room?

Here is some sample data to help explain what I want:

```
     action      | date
------------------------------
sample action 1  | 2021-03-01
sample action 2  | 2021-03-02
sample action 3  | 2021-03-03
sample action 4  | 2021-03-04
sample action 5  | 2021-03-05
sample action 6  | 2021-03-06
sample action 7  | 2021-03-09
sample action 8  | 2021-03-09
sample action 9  | 2021-03-10
sample action 10 | 2021-03-11
sample action 11 | 2021-03-12
```

So the longest streak would be the 6 days from 2021-03-01 through 2021-03-06, and the current streak would be 4 days (2021-03-09 through 2021-03-12).

Comment: Does it need to be achieved via a `Room` query, or can you read all the data into a `List` and analyse it there?

Comment: @codebod the ideal solution for me would be a room query for each streak (current and longest), but if I can achieve this another way that may work too.

Comment: Post sample data and expected results to clarify what you want.

Comment: @forpas i updated the question to explain in more detail.

Comment: I see there are duplicate days: `2021-03-09`. Why the current streak isn't 5?

Comment: @forpas because I only want to return the consecutive number of days, ignoring duplicates. Multiple actions can be recorded on the same day.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use window functions `LAG()` and `SUM()` to create 1 group for each streak and then aggregate to count the rows of each group:

```
WITH cte AS (
  SELECT SUM(COALESCE(flag, 1)) OVER (ORDER BY date) grp
  FROM (
    SELECT *, DATE(date, '-1 day') <> LAG(date) OVER (ORDER BY date) flag
    FROM (SELECT DISTINCT date FROM tablename)
  )
)  
SELECT MAX(COUNT(*)) OVER () longest_streak, 
       COUNT(*) current_streak 
FROM cte
GROUP BY grp
ORDER BY grp DESC LIMIT 1
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlite_3.27&fiddle=f8c5112cefff2ddf29945f28a7cc8aa0).
Results:

| longest_streak | current_streak |
| --- | --- |
| 6 | 4 |

Comment: So it worked fine on my emulator, but not on physical devices. Apparently window functions and android aren't a supported thing yet. Is there a way to accomplish this without windows functions?

Comment: @Martin window functions were introduced in SQLite in version 3.25.0 (2018-09-15). I guess you want to support versions of Android that have lower versions. I did try to make a more general solution without window functions, but it is far more complicated and much worse in performance. Check this: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlite_3.27&fiddle=b70f9d3b8afa44b708e8d543875c6fee The problem is to get both values in a single query.

Comment: @Martin Or this: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlite_3.27&fiddle=c91e717db8f195f1c4266823b98bd984 if your Android-SQLite version supports CTEs.

Comment: I was able to use the query with the Requery library alongside Room. Your answer is now working on both. Thanks again

Comment: Playing with your query and trying to figure a way to determine a streak from a specified date that would return 0 if no activity recorded that day and the day preceding it. Not having much luck